# Cannot refer to tables with computed virtual columns in triggers of MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This seems to be a bug in `MySql`. Posting it here to confirm my conclusion and share my experience. We are currently migrating from MS SQL Server to `MySql Community Edition 5.7.12`. There is a `Dealers` table which has a virtual computed column. It was being referred in the join of a query used inside a trigger. As a result of this, the MySql Server got re-started.

To make sure that there was no other cause to the event, we had created a dummy table *without computed columns* and referred to that table in the trigger. The trigger executed successfully. Then, we had created another dummy table *with the computed column*. We had just referred the table in the join without the reference to the computed column. When the trigger was fired, the server crashed inspite of the fact that only a actual column of the table was referred and there was no reference to the computed column. Thus, you cannot even refer a table with computed columns in the triggers.

What we have done temporarily is to convert the virtual columns into actual columns and modified the queries of select, insert and update on the table.

Is there a better alternative to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your test example?. I can't reproduce the problem on my test example.

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.12    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  `t2`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  `t1`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

-- Table with Generated Column
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
    ->   `c0` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `value` VARCHAR(20),
    ->   `c1` INTEGER UNSIGNED GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`c0`) VIRTUAL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t2` (
    ->   `c1` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `value` VARCHAR(20)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `t2` (`c1`, `value`) VALUES (1, 'value 1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ||

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `t1_ins_bef`||
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `t1_ins_bef` BEFORE INSERT ON `t1`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SET NEW.`value` := (SELECT `t2`.`value`
    ->                       FROM `t1`
    ->                         INNER JOIN `t2` ON `t1`.`c1` = `t2`.`c1`);
    -> END||
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> INSERT INTO `t1` (`c0`) VALUES (1), (2);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `c0`,
    ->   `value`,
    ->   `c1`
    -> FROM
    ->   `t1`;
+----+---------+------+
| c0 | value   | c1   |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 | NULL    |    1 |
|  2 | value 1 |    2 |
+----+---------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `c1`,
    ->   `value`
    -> FROM
    ->   `t2`;
+----+---------+
| c1 | value   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | value 1 |
+----+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```